# video.js - "stop-and-go" video play

Tags: video, video.js

I use the `video.js` player to play my mp4-files. The player is configures with `autoplay=true`, `preload=auto` and `loop=true.` If the user visit the site the video start playing after a second. But the video is playing with many "load" pause and resumes...the second round plays perfect. It seems to not loading fast enough because he is loading constant from the beginning. Maybe the buffersize/buffertime is to small?! But how can I modify these parameters? Is there a other possible misconfiguration? Is there a way to preload the whole video before starting the clip?